# How should this sink be vented?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

We are remodeling our kitchen and moving the sink from against a wall to a peninsula.

You can see below what the plumber put in.  The new sink drain is lower left (in blue).  The drain eventually flows into the slab at lower right green.  The vent for the old sink is in red.

[image]

I'm new to this, but from what I've read, the only way this work as-is is to install an AAV under the sink.  However, I think AAVs are not code in San Diego (where I live).  Also it looks to me like a loop vent would not be hard to install (see the second photo where I've sketched one in):

[image]

Does that seem reasonable?  Am I right to think the plumber should not have installed it this way to begin with and should fix it?

**More details**:

I found this in the California Plumbing Code (https://up.codes/viewer/california/ca-plumbing-code-2016/chapter/10/traps-and-interceptors#1002.2).

[image]

It seems pretty clear that this is not code.  The full length of the drain line in the photo is ~140" which is much longer than the longest allow distance in the table above.  Am I reading/thinking about this correctly?

Comment: I think i would have gone with a 2x6 island wall, ( *thicker wall for all the plumbing clearance you need* )  a sanitary tee for the sink drain with  vent out the top, through the wall and tie into the old  vent stack.

Comment: Can you go up into attic with a wet vent just to the right of sink base?